# How to make numpy.reshape to work as a specific for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4 dimension list that contains numpy arrays. The following general shape is expected for this list `num_batches,50,batch_size,27`. The last batch (i.e., `num_batches = -1`) usually has instances less than `batch_size`. So, if you loop over the first axis and print the dimension you will see something like: `(50,100,27),(50,100,27),...,(50,100,27),(50,85,27)` I would like to reshape it such that it has the dimensions `50,all_samples_num,27`, where `all_samples_num` is the sum of the second dimension of the printed dimensions. At first, I wrote the following for loop:

```
tt = np.empty((50,0,27))
for ttt in x:
    i = i + 1
    tmp = []
    for t in ttt:
        tmp.append(t)
    tt = np.append(tt, np.array(tmp),axis=1)
```

When I wanted to optimize the code, I used the following reshaping code:

```
xx = np.array(x[:-1].tolist()).reshape(50,-1,27)
xx = np.concatenate((xx,np.array(x[-1].tolist()).reshape(50,-1,27)),axis=0)
```

However, `tt` and `xx` are not equivalent. I tried C-order and F-order of `reshape` but still the resulting array is not equivalent to `tt`. How can I manipulate `reshape` such that it does give something identical to `tt`?

Comment: So, when it's all done, you want to concatenate these arrays so you have one that is `(50,large,27)`?

Comment: @TimRoberts, right but I need it to preserve the order as it would be in the for loop. I mean the dimensionality is not the problem but rather the content.

Answer (score 0):

"concatenate" is the API you are seeking.  "reshape" changes the interpretation of the addressing without really changing the data.

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randint(100,size=(50,5,27))
x2 = np.random.randint(100,size=(50,15,27))
x3 = np.random.randint(100,size=(50,9,27))
x4 = np.random.randint(100,size=(50,3,27))

i = np.concatenate( (x1,x2,x3,x4), axis=1)
print(i.shape)
```